# How to receive a specific file thru BizTalk FTP receive port

Tags: ftp, biztalk

My orchestration receives a message that contains a file name and I want to pick that file from my FTP. I can configure FTP receive port to receive all files from some folder in the FTP, but how do I receive a file with specific name?

The process looks like
[image: process draft]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather recommend your solution of writing a custom .NET component which will fetch the file from FTP location (you can call that component from your expression shape).

Dynamically creating Receive Ports/Receive locations and later removing them won't scale and possibly will get you into serious trouble.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I've commented about earlier

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if [this link](http://geekswithblogs.net/bloesgen/archive/2008/05/13/122120.aspx) helps - specifically the CreateFtpReceiveLocation method - i.e. programatically adding a receive location (pseudo dynamic receive location).

You would also need to remove the location afterwards. I'm guessing that you can also set the FileMask on the Transport Properties of the 'dynamic' Location to the filename in the Custom Props of the TransportTypeData, and would need to remove the Location once you are done with the file.

Comment: Thanks @nonnb! I've seen the article but I think it's a way too complex. I came to conclusion that I can place an Expression shape and inside it I can call external lib which would do whatever I want :) Not sure if this a perfect solution but still it's an easy one.